# Xiaomi Mi True Wireless Earphones 2 Pro - With Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

Just got Xiaomi Mi True Wireless Earphones 2 Pro.
Managed to pair it with the phone without a problem but can't pair it with Ubuntu.
I go to Settings - Bluetooth, I turn it on and let it scan.
It does not find the earphones.
It does however finds other devices and managed to connect to them (like my phone).
So Bluetooth seems to work...but can't find the earphones.
Any ideas? a very an unexperienced linux user here...
Thank you!